# How we can deploy clickonce application as a Prerequisit?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, clickonce

I want to deploy `Clickonce` application with another setup which was generated by **InstallShield 2013**.

After some search i found how to create a custom prerequisite (below are the steps.)

1. Created file "MyPrerequisit.prq" at location "C:\Program Files\InstallShild\2010\SetupPrerequisites"
2. Then in IS 2013 Redistributables view, i confiqured "MyPrerequisit.prq".
3. When i run the setup.

It show the Clickonce as Prerequisite and launch it successfully but setup dont wait for the Prerequisit installation completed.